# Using Sandbox servers with apns

Tags: python, ios, apple-push-notifications

What is the difference between using Apple's sandbox servers or not with push notifications? For example:

```
apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='cert.pem', key_file='key.pem')
```

vs.

```
apns = APNs(use_sandbox=False, cert_file='cert.pem', key_file='key.pem')
```

Why would someone care if they are using Apple's sandbox servers or not? Is there an actual reason why it should be used or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the sandbox while you are in staging and production server while you have deployed ad hoc or on AppStore.

The reason is to keep test environment distinct from production.
When you create an application you need to set different certificates and provisioning profile to sign the app. Basically one for debug and one for distribution. If you want to add push functionalities you must create 2 certificates to communicate with APNS. Push test certificates only works in sandbox with app signed with debug certificates, while Push production certificates only works with app signed using a distribution cert.
It's quite common to keep test environment distinct from production, sometimes I work with 3 environments: test, stage, production. One for pure testing, one for understand if everything works as expected before going to production.
Suppose that you already have an application on App Store that uses Push notification, now you'd like to publish a new version of the app that enhance or modify something in the payload of the notification. Wouldn't by nice if you could test that new payload in an eviroment different from the one in the App Store? so you can take your time to see if everything is working correctly and maybe check if the changes doesn't affect the old app.That is the purpose of sandbox.

Did I answer your question?